# Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required

Tags: php, joomla, cpanel, require-once

This is the first time I upload a site - http://indianrestaurantmumbai.com/ , I have added everything necessary to my folder (I think), and it gives me this error message:

```
Warning: require_once(/home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/includes/defines.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/index.php on line 21


Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/includes/defines.php' (include_path='.:/usr/lib/php:/usr/local/lib/php') in /home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/index.php on line 21
```

Can please someone help me out?

Comment: It's because the path you're including from is not correct in relation to how the structure of your documents  actually is. You can try something like `require_once $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/includes/defines.php";` instead, or finding the real path of the document by adding `echo __FILE__;` and accessing that script - and use that absolute path.

Comment: I removed the "require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );"  "require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );"  and it only left "Fatal error: Call to a member function mark() on null in /home/ecoconst/public_html"/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/index.php on line 21

Comment: @Qirel it must be something in my configuration.php i just dont know what.

Comment: You know, without seeing your code, those errors and what you just explained means very little. Nobody here can read minds ;-) As I said, try to include the files with help of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']`, like explained above. As for the `Call to a member function mark() on null`, can't help without seeing what that code does.

Comment: I found the solution, simply the .htaccess was looking for first page "index.html" and my .html file was "Index.html" with capital "I", thank you anyway :)

Answer (score 1):

The error actually seems clear. The file:

> /home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/includes/defines.php

does not seem to exist on your hosting account. The path seems correct, comparing it with the one of your index.php file that tries to reference the defines.php.

I would recommend that you confirm that the file defines.php is properly uploaded in:

> /home/ecoconst/public_html/IndianRestaurantMumbai.com/includes

and if so, please make sure that it's permissions are 644 or 755.

If this is an existing Joomla and the file is missing, I would recommend that you contact your hosting provider and see if they are using ConfigServer eXploit Scanner (cxs). If your Joomla has been compromised, the scanner often quarantines files, resulting in similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, simply the .htaccess was looking for first page "index.html" and my .html file was "Index.html" with capital "I", so I just renamed it and everything was fine.