# Fatal error when access Wordpress site uploaded by ftp

Tags: php, wordpress

I am uploading my Wordpress site to a hosting by ftp. It uploads well, but I see the following errors when I try to access the website:

> Warning: require_once(/home/content/90/8733390/html/marreroinmobiliaria.com/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/real-estate-search.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /home/content/90/8733390/html/marreroinmobiliaria.com/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/load.php on line 22
>
> Fatal error: require_once(): Failed opening required '/home/content/90/8733390/html/marreroinmobiliaria.com/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/real-estate-search.php' (include_path='.:/usr/local/php5_4/lib/php') in /home/content/90/8733390/html/marreroinmobiliaria.com/wp-content/themes/realhomes/framework/functions/load.php on line 22

What could be? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Are those files there and readable by your web server user?

Comment: could it be a path problem similar to this [SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36113216/fatal-error-require-once-failed-opening-required) ?

Comment: Are you sure the theme "realhomes" has the file "real-estate-search.php" inside "realhomes/framework/functions/" ?

Comment: Hi, It seems like the ftp server drops the file "real-estate-search.php", I upload with Filezilla the file and quickily disappear from the server. Any suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like there is some part of the link before public HTML (the part before the domain name in the error message) that must be included in your php

Comment: this drove me nuts when I was trying to learn php - I was searching everywhere for this unwanted precursor to the link to try to remove the penny dropped and I actually included it after document root